# Getting Private Repos From Organization with GitHub API V3

Tags: jquery, git, api, github, github-api

I am having trouble obtaining and organizing private repos.  I am using API V3 with this method: http://share.jjnford.com/HhIZ

I am using the jQuery.getJSON command and passing my OAuth2 access token to the API URL but am only getting public repositories returns.

Also if I fork a private organization repository to a user account (context) and pull the users repositories all the repos (public & private) show up except the private repo forked from an organization.

Can anybody help me out with this... it is my last hurdle...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The link in the question is no longer working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem and corrected it.  According the the [GitHub API V3 there are multiple scopes](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) that can be used.  It seems the the "user" scope is not valid anymore.  Once I used just the "repo" scope everything was retrieved correctly (private org repos, and private forked org repos).

Comment: The doc you're linking to says 'user' is a valid scope. Do you actually know why your changes worked or are you just guessing that the docs are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a correct answer for this at the time, and I don't want to ask for the scope "repo" since it's too overkill for my application, it asks for code read/write permssions. Here's what worked for me (I'm using Ruby along with the octokit gem (https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb)), special thanks to Ivan from the github dev support:

1.- During Oauth, ask for the "read:org" scope and get the Oauth 2 token from Github

2.- initialize octokit's client:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: my_oauth2_token)
```

3.- Retrieve the user's organizations, we can do it because of the "read:org" scope

```
organizations = client.organizations
```

4.- For each organization, retrieve a Github admin Team to which this user belongs. And then, use this Team to retrieve the repos available

```
organizations.each do |organization|
    admin_team = client.organization_teams(organization[:id]).select { |repo| repo[:permission] == 'admin' }.first
    org_repos << client.team_repositories(admin_team[:id])
end
```

Yes, you will definitely need more requests to gather all the available repos, but as I said before, In my case, I did not want to ask for the "user" scope.

Note: Yes, the user have to be a member of an "admin" Team within a given Organization to be able to see the private repos.