# Calling the Github API as a proxy user

Tags: github, github-api

I have a collection of private repos and issues, that I would like to expose to users of my site.

Is it possible to list those on a page in my site, without the user having to have a github account and access to those repos?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. LinkedIn offered the capability to list Github repos on your profile via one of the apps.

[This question mentions a user doing just that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975848/getting-private-repos-from-organization-with-github-api-v3).