# How can I use Git CLI to get the latest release?

Tags: git, bash, github, command-line-interface

I would like to use the GitHub "releases" feature to tell my production server when should it update its code base from GitHub.
I do not want it to grab on each push, but just when a new release is being created.

My plan was to create a Bash script that will check every 10-15 minutes if there is a new release and if it found a new release, it will do a pull request or download the latest release [ZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) file, deploy the new code and restart the node service.

But I am stuck on the first step. How can I figure out if there is a new release?

Comment: One important thing that I forgot to mention is that it is a Private GitHub.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in "[GitHub latest release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28594480/6309)", you have an API dedicated to get the latest release.

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest
```

You can use it (with the [appropriate authentication](https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#authentication) and the [right scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322008/6309)) for a private repo.

If you cache the latest release, you can trigger your process each time the new latest differs from the one you have cached.

---

Alternatively [gh release list](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_list) display releases, and since [gh 2.18.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.18.0) (Nov. 2022), with [column title](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/6323#issuecomment-1298937281):

```
$ gh release list
TITLE                   TYPE         TAG NAME      PUBLISHED
GitHub CLI 2.18.1       Latest       v2.18.1       about 12 days ago
GitHub CLI 2.18.0                    v2.18.0       about 14 days ago
```

Answer (score 2):

CLI `gh release list` command can show the release date

Answer (score 1):

Using bash with the help of curl, you can use this long one-liner to get the latest release from a public repository:

```
git clone -b $(basename $(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} https://github.com/OWNER/PROJECT/releases/latest)) https://github.com/OWNER/PROJECT.git
```

A bash function like this:

```
gh-clone-latest() {
  local owner=$1 project=$2
  local output_directory=${3:-$owner-$project-release}
  local release_url=$(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} https://github.com/$owner/$project/releases/latest)
  local release_tag=$(basename $release_url)
  git clone -b $release_tag -- https://github.com/$owner/$project.git $output_directory
}
```

would reduce that to `gh-clone-latest Owner Project`.

For a private project, you'll need to authenticate and scope properly, as mentioned in the other answer.